# VBA Change image on userform

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am using this code for a user to change the image on a UserForm.

```
Private Sub image_logo_Click()
    Dim filetoOpen
    filetoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Image Files (*.jpg;*.gif), *.jpg;*.gif")
    If filetoOpen <> False Then
        image_logo.Picture = LoadPicture(filetoOpen)
    Form.Repaint
End Sub
```

It works fine but then for some reason when I go to the VBA Editor, the image reverts back to the old one. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: If you assign to `image_logo.Picture` the change will only last while the code is running, when it ends and you return to the editor it will be lost.  Use the properties window of the Picturebox to add a permanent image.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Perhaps storing the image on a hidden worksheet ?

Comment: Save the path in `filetoOpen`. When the form loads try to read it back, if it exists, `LoadPicture` it

Comment: You could insert the picture to a hidden sheet, then you will have to export it to a drive location, and then import it with LoadPicture method again.

Comment: That wouldn't be ideal as the spreadsheet will move around to other computers..

Comment: could we not load the picture from the hidden sheet directly? and write code for the image to be stored in the hidden sheet initially? will that stick?